# How to render two object in same z position in Open Gl?

Tags: python, opengl

I load a `Candide3D` model  **self.drawFace(vertices)** and load a hat 3D model **glCallList(obj.gl_list)**, but when I change the **z** position of the hat, it never stay on the `Candidie3` model.
I also changed the **gluPerspective(50,self.w/float(self.h), 1 , 250.0)** camera matrix but, in almost every case the hat render in front of `Candide3` model.

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)        
    glLoadIdentity()
    setOrtho(self.w, self.h)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)
    self.drawFace(vertices)
    glDepthMask( GL_TRUE )

    ######## render next model ##########

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,  (-40, 50, 100, 0.0))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH) 

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(50,self.w/float(self.h), 1 , 250.0)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture_image2)
    glTranslate(self.tx,self.ty,-40)
    self.tx,self.ty=self.track(shape2D)
    glRotate(ry, 1, 0, 0)        
    glPushMatrix()
    glCallList(obj.gl_list)
    glPopMatrix()     
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

Comment: def setOrtho(w, h):
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, -200, 200)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)  , this is  setOrtho(w, h): function

Comment: if you mean the glMatrix Mode(GL_MODELVIEW) , i set it in setOrtho(w, h) function ??

Comment: sorry ,  I did your task but ,not change any thing ,  I want my hat obj load on face model . like a gun in hand or glasses on face , but i cant render it !

Comment: Why do you disable depth buffer writes during the first render?

Comment: If i enable depth buffer my hat model apear in background of candide3 model .

Comment: Well, you change the projection matrix in-between the objects. SO what do you expect? None of that does make any sense.

Comment: No i want to render two model on each other ,but with change the projection matrix ,  it only change  length of second obj

Comment: "it only change length of second obj", no, it also make the depth values between those two renderings completely incompatible, so that it will just screw the depth test.